# Renamed executable files Cmd and Utilman and now its not opening

Tags: windows-command-prompt

I forgot my windows password
So I tried to change "Accessibility" to "Cmd" on Sign-in windows by following these steps:

Opened Advanced Startup Menu > Trouble Shoot > Advanced Options > Cmd

In cmd I renamed my files in my System32 :

1)Renamed utilman.exe to utilman1.exe
2)cmd.exe to utilman.exe

I tried renaming it back to it's default name
But it's not working for me and I'm unable to open both Accessibility and CMD :(

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that PowerShell is installed on your machine, run it in admin mode, then navigate to `C:\Windows\system32\` and run `sfc /scannow`, then perform a system reboot.

Can you open run `cmd.exe` in safe mode or with another user profile on the same windows machine? If so, you might have an issue with your user profile. How about if you try to run it by specifying the full path from the run command. If you share the specific errors you are getting, it will be much easier to help you.